# Why does my function's name appear twice in the "locals" window?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a Class Module in which I have defined a function. Whenever that function is called, it is listed twice in the locals window. Only the second one's value changes, the first one stays either empty or "zero", depending on its type, until the end of the code's execution. I don't have this problem with functions defined in standard modules. Did I do something wrong, is this a bug, or is there a logical reason behind this?

**Contents of the TestClass class module:**

```
Public Value As Double

Function AddFive() As Double
    AddFive = Me.Value + 5
End Function
```

**Contents of the standard module:**

```
Sub TestSub()
    Dim TestObject As New TestClass
    TestObject.Value = 2
    MsgBox TestObject.AddFive
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot showing that, when the code is executed line-by-line, the function's value is listed twice in the locals window, and only the second value has changed after the function's code was executed.

[(link to screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHO87.png)

I'm using VBA for Excel 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an implicit variable in a VBA function with the same name as the function.  The one you assign in your snippet.  The one that changes is that implicit variable, the one that doesn't is the actual function return value, evaluated only after you step out of the function.

Comment: The function's return value doesn't appear in the locals window if the function is defined in a standard module. Only the implicit variable appears then, why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more in how you are doing it. If you have a function that just adds 5 to an internal variable of a class object, then it's technically a void (Sub in VBA) since you don't  need a return value.

Your code should be:

CLASS

```
Public Value As Double

Sub AddFive()
    Me.Value = Me.Value + 5
End Sub
```

MODULE

```
Sub test()

Dim testObject As New TestClass
testObject.Value = 2
testObject.AddFive

MsgBox testObject.Value

End Sub
```

I can imagine there could be a number of reasons why there are 2 variables created, but I find it a bit pointless to go into why there is unexpected behavior since you are doing improper code.

If you want, you can even write class function that will show it's value + 5 in a msgbox and this would not create an extra variable either. But that is strange and I think you want the code above. But here it is regardless:

CLASS

```
Public Value As Double

Sub ShowPlusFive()
    MsgBox Me.Value + 5
End Sub
```

MODULE

```
Sub test()

Dim testObject As New TestClass
testObject.Value = 2

testObject.ShowPlusFive

End Sub
```

Comment: I chose this example for the sake of simplicity. I'm not trying to avoid creating a second variable, I'm trying to understand why it is created.

Comment: My guess is that VBA uses one variable in the module (the MsgBox needs  something returned to it) and the class function also creates a return value (the one that is eventually passed to the MsgBox in the module). The one that is 0 is most likely the module one before it is passed the return value from your class function. It's just a guess, though, and the example is a little funky since you normally wouldn't be using a function with a return value in the msgbox call.

Comment: I imagine that the msgbox implicitly creates the variable when it hits the MsgBox line since it knows it needs somewhere to temp. store the return value, and the class function will create it's own return value  variable since it's supposed to be associated with the class member (it won't just piggy back and use the temp. variable created by the MsgBox call in the main module). That would explain why you don't this behavior in just normal modules (class member functions are probably set up like this).